# Terminology: vertices in every cycle in a graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, terminology

Let $\mathcal{G} = (V, E)$ be a (directed or undirected)
graph. Call a set $S \subseteq V$ *cycle-needed* if every cycle in
$\mathcal{G}$ has at least one vertex in $S$. We say $S$ is *minimally*
cycle-needed if no cycle-needed set has a strictly smaller cardinality than $S$. In the example below the two  red nodes are cycle-needed but not minimally so, while
the yellow node is minimally cycle-needed.

[image: Example graph]

What are    the 'official' names of cycle-neededness and minimal
cycle-neededness in mathematics?

Comment: As more general terminology, I would say that, though the yellow set is *minimum* with this property (it has the least possible size) both the yellow and red sets are *minimal* (you can't remove any vertex from them and keep the property). This is a confusing but commonly used distinction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cycle-needed set is sometimes called a *decycling set*, and the size of a minimum cycle-needed set is called the *decycling number* of a graph (see [The Decycling Numbers of Graphs](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0703544) by Bau and Beineke).

There's also terminology for the complementary notion: $S \subseteq V$ intersects every cycle of the graph $\mathcal G$ if and only if the subgraph induced by its complement $T = V \setminus S$ is a forest. As a result, looking for minimum decycling sets is equivalent to looking for maximum induced forests.

Somehow finding maximum induced trees in graphs has attracted more attention (there's a paper on this: [Maximum Induced Trees in Graphs](https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1986-08.pdf) by Erdős, Saks, and Sós) but the problem is not equivalent even when $\mathcal G$ is connected. For example, in the butterfly graph

[image: butterfly graph]

there is an induced forest of size $4$ (corresponding to the minimum decycling set of size $1$: the middle vertex) but only an induced tree of size $3$. But there are people talking about induced forests as well, especially in planar graphs (see [this overview](http://www.math.illinois.edu/~dwest/openp/planforest.html)).

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea that decycling was in Karp's original NP paper.